# Switch from Dialect.registerHibernateType() to MetadataBuilderContributor.applyBasicType() in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 5.6.4 and I'm trying to get rid of a custom dialect implementation and switch to a MetadataBuilderContributor.

I successfully managed to replace a bunch of `registerFunction("abc", new StandardSQLFunction("abc", IntegerType.INSTANCE))` with `metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("abc", new StandardSQLFunction("abc", IntegerType.INSTANCE))`.

However, in my custom dialect I still have an overridden type definition `registerHibernateType(Types.NVARCHAR, 1000, "string")` that allows me to define a capacity of 1000 in my case. I can not figure out what the corresponding approach is. I expect it has something to do with `metadataBuilder.applyBasicType(new StringNVarcharType())` or something similar. I don't want to define a new type but to customize the NVarchar capacity as in the dialect implementation.